# Rotate just one Quad in 2D

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

In OpenGL, for the following situation in 2D, how can I rotate this one quad - and only this one quad (everything else in the scene should stay where it is)?

```
// Draw in immediate mode
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                      // begin drawing quads
glVertex2f(box.x,box.y);                // top-left corner
glVertex2f(box.x+box.w,box.y);          // top-right corner
glVertex2f(box.x+box.w,box.y+box.h);    // bottom-right corner
glVertex2f(box.x,box.y+box.h);          // bottom-left corner
glEnd();                                // end drawing quads
```

`glRotatef(angle, x,y,z)` seems to rotate my whole scene.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in glPushMatrix and popMatrix

```
glPushMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW);

glRotatef(angle, x,y,z);

// Draw in immediate mode
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                      // begin drawing quads
glVertex2f(box.x,box.y);                // top-left corner
glVertex2f(box.x+box.w,box.y);          // top-right corner
glVertex2f(box.x+box.w,box.y+box.h);    // bottom-right corner
glVertex2f(box.x,box.y+box.h);          // bottom-left corner
glEnd();                                // end drawing quads

glPopMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Basically in the above example you are pushing the modevliew matrix one position up into the stack, saving it in an essence. Then you rotate the modelview and draw your quad.
Afterwards you pop back one position in the modelview taking back to how it was before the rotation and the drawing.

Comment: So what do I need to pass to `glRotatef` in order to have it rotate my quad by say 90deg?

Comment: @Ben: Did you even bother to look at [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) for glRotate? It clearly says, "Specifies the angle of rotation, in degrees." That page is literally the first result from searching for "glRotatef" in Google.

Comment: @Nicol I am not sure what to pass for `x,y,z` such that it rotates the whole object and not just one vector.

Comment: @Ben the documentation is pretty clear. If you want it to rotate say for 45 degrees around the x axis then just do: glRotatef(45,1,0,0);

Comment: To better understand it this x,y,z is actually a vector. The vector around which your scene/object will get rotated by ANGLE degrees. 
So by giving 1,0,0 you rotate it around the X axis

Comment: I want to rotate it say 45 deg about its *center* in the 2D plane that it lies in.

Comment: you want to rotate it around the y axis? or the x axis? 
In openGL by default the x Axis goes from the left of the screen to the right, the y axis from bottom to top and the z axis from you towards the screen.

Comment: I want to rotate my Quad about its center, so in terms of axis I assume I would need to move it to the origin and then rotate it about the z-axis? (the quad lies in the xy-plane)